# What is , "You haven't cast a vote to undo"

Tags: support, status-norepro, voting

I want to upvote an answer, I previously down voted. It shows
"You haven't cast a vote to undo".
.
How do I cast one?

Comment: Sorry for trouble! It was just app bug. When I closed app and reopened question my upvote was already registered.

Comment: For future reference, if you want to report a problem you're having in the app, it is _essential_ that you say you're having the problem in the app. Otherwise we'll assume it exists on the website.

Comment: Also for future reference, problems with the app are much better handled on [meta.se].

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I did not know, it was a bug with app. Or I would have definitely posted it there.